# How do I go about solving this triangle problem?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: This is a problem for Core COurse for A level by Bostock]

So how do I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Study the following figure:

[image]

Comment: can I assume that the part at the back is a rectangle and that the two heights of the two triangles are equal?

Comment: @neophyte Yes, you can. The ridge of the roof has a constant height.

Comment: Thanks for the diagram, I was stuck with the problem because I couldn't identify that the triangle at the bottom (with angle theta) was also a right angled triangle.

Comment: You're welcome:)